# How to expand width of gridview column?

Tags: android, tablelayout, grid-layout

In my android app, I create a gridview using java code, and insert rows. There is 3 columns in it, and I want the second column to fill the screen. For example, right now, the gridview only fills 20% of the screen in width. I want it to fill the whole screen, the second column should expand. The problem is I don't know how to set a weight on the column, since u just insert views in it.

I tried setting a weight of 1, on the views in the 2nd column, but it didn't work...

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:stretchMode` in the xml in order to stretch the gridview to will the whole parent view.
 `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"` will stretch each column equally and fill the view